# Python join filepath and filename

Tags: python

I am browsing for a file  which works fine :

```
def fileDialog(self):
    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file", filetypes = 
    (("excel files","*.xl*"),("all files","*.*")))
self.uploadRoster()
```

By selection that particular excel file, I can convert the excel file into database ; however, the database is created in same location but I want to copy the database to the directory where my script is saved or some other desired folder but this won't work.

```
def uploadRoster(self):
    response = messagebox.askquestion(title = "Upload Roster", message = "Do you wish to continue?")
    if response == 'yes':
        excel_file = self.filename
        connection = sqlite3.connect(os.path.splitext(excel_file)[0] + ".db")
        wb = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = [0])
        for sheet in wb:
            wb[sheet].to_sql("employee_details", connection, index=False, if_exists = 'append')
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
    elif response == 'no':
        pass
```

Above will convert the file(example "Roster.xlxs to "Roster.db") but this should be saved in other directory because later I don't have access to the location of "Roster.xlxs" path....
Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Are you familiar with [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)? Also, when working with paths, you should really prefer to work with [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: I have tried with os.path.join... Let me explain
source_destination = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(excel_file), "Roster.db")
print(source_destination)

When I print this, it gives = C:/Projects\Roster.db
However, the correct path should be C:/Projects/Roster.db

Once it's fixed, I can then copy the file to another directory

Comment: This is why it is better to use `pathlib`... `os.path` treats paths as simple strings and does operations on strings. `pathlib` treats them as `Path` object and knows to parse them more cleverly

Answer (score 1):

You can set the new path for your database at these lines;

```
# ... logic ....
if response == 'yes':
    excel_file = self.filename
    connection = sqlite3.connect(os.path.splitext(excel_file)[0] + ".db")
# .... logic
```

For example;

```
def uploadRoster(self):
    response = messagebox.askquestion(title = "Upload Roster", message = "Do you wish to continue?")
    if response == 'yes':
        excel_file = self.filename

        # extract the name 
        name = os.path.splitext(excel_file)[0]

        # create new path for your db 
        # you may want to use os.path.join() here
        path = 'path_to/your_folder/' + name + '.db' 

        # create db at specified path
        connection = sqlite3.connect(path)

        wb = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = [0])
        for sheet in wb:
            wb[sheet].to_sql("employee_details", connection, index=False, if_exists = 'append')

        connection.commit()
        connection.close()

    elif response == 'no':
        pass
```

Comment: I have below error -------------------------

connection = sqlite3.connect(path)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Comment: Can you print the ```path``` and check the path to your folder exists ?

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

```
import sqlite3
dbdir='C:\\Temp\\SQL\\' #put your path here
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbdir+'example.db')
```